# Parsing and checking validity of the date from numbers

Tags: java

I want to check the existence of the date, I have int variables ( representing format ) - day( dd ), month ( MM ) and year ( YY ). Here's my code:

```
    SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("YYMMdd");
    df.setLenient(false);

    try {
        Date d = df.parse(""+day+month+year);
    } ...
```

Because variables are in int I have problem when day for example can be 01 ( 1 digit in int ), or 21 ( 2 digits in int ) and I'm getting error as I have 'dd' in my format. Is there an easy way how I can use my numbers to check the validity of the date?

Comment: Didn't you mean `Date d = df.parse(""+year+month+day);`? (year first, day last)

Comment: You could change your date format to `"YYMd"`

Comment: thanks man, "YYMd" definitely should solve my problem ;P

Comment: @Ir0nm  Not really. How about 13111? Is it 11-Jan or 1-Nov?

Comment: @assylias - Good point... That's not going to work without separators.  Oops!

Comment: So it's possible to add separators 'YY:M:d' and then parse string with ':' between numbers

Comment: @Ir0nm I think you are overcomplicating it.

Comment: Please read some documentation... Everything about parsing dates is covered in depth in the API documentation.  You can read it [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html). However, the [answer by assylias](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17073396/778118) is definitely the easiest way to achieve your goal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have the day, month and year in numeric format, it would be easier to create a date directly:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.clear(); //to set the time to 00:00:00.0000 if that is an issue
cal.set(year, month, day);
Date dt = cal.getTime();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pad your number strings like this:

```
String paddedDay = String.format("%02d", day);
```